# Printing an array by recursion in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I am trying to write a function to print an array by recursion.

I have written three functions but they seems to be the same in terms of principle.

```
void printArray0( int theArray[], int theSize, int theIndex = 0 )
{
    cout << theArray[theIndex] << ' ';
    if ( ++theIndex != theSize ) printArray0( theArray, theSize, theIndex );
    else cout << endl;
}

void printArray1( int theArray[], int theElementLeft )
{
    cout << *theArray << ' ';
    if ( theElementLeft != 1 ) printArray1( theArray+1, theElementLeft-1 );
    else cout << endl;
}

void printArray2( int theArray[], int theSize )
{
    static int myIndex = 0;
    cout << theArray[myIndex] << ' ';
    if ( ++myIndex != theSize ) printArray2( theArray, theSize );
    else cout << endl;
}
```

So are there significant differences between them?

If there are, which function is the fastest and which is the safest?

I hope I can learn from others' experience :)

Comment: I never had this experience :)

Comment: Who knows what shadows lurk in the hearts of code? Only the profiler knows!

Comment: All three will fail when the given size is 0.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, a new adventure begins!

Comment: I guess the fastest and safest way is using a loop...

Comment: @AlexFarber No! Too fast, too easy, too readable, too safe! How will you ever win [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/) with a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third one is not equivalent to the first two, because it uses a static variable to keep the current state. This is a bad thing (imagine running this function from multiple threads concurrently to see why). The reason this even works is that there is never more than one recursive invocation from each invocation of a function. For example, trying to keep a static state in a recursive traversal of a binary tree would fail rather miserably. That is why the current state should be passed through parameters to your recursive functions, without using static or member context.

There should be no performance difference between the first two versions, because their time will be dominated by the output of the data.

I would change the signature of the second function like this

```
void printArray1( int *theArray, int theElementLeft )
```

because you never use `theArray` as an array, only as a pointer. Technically it does not matter because arrays "decay" to pointers anyway, but I think this would slightly improve readability.

Answer (score 3):

Functions 0 and 1 are equally safe<sup>1</sup>.

Function 2 is not safe in a multithreaded environment because it makes use of a static variable.  Additionally, successive calls to this function will start where the last call "left off", because `myIndex` is never re-initialized to zero anywhere.

---

<sup>1</sup>Personally I would prefer the style of function 1 over function 0.  Function 0 is clever in its use of pre-increment (`if ( ++theIndex != theSize )`) and this cleverness, in my opinion, will hamper future maintenance.  A condition that has side-effects is something I would suggest that you avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of them make much sense, there is no reason why anyone would ever use recursion for this. The first version is probably least bad, since it is easiest to read.

The version with `static` is most dangerous since it isn't thread safe. And using static makes the whole recursion (even more) pointless.

Generally, there are very few cases where recursion makes sense, this is not one of them. All three versions are dangerous, since there are no guarantees that the recursion will stop if the parameters are incorrect. All three versions will consume much more RAM memory than a plain loop and they will execute slower, while also making your program far less readable. Your program will be vulnerable to stack overflows.

Compilers typically don't optimize recursion all that efficiently. Whether they do or not may depend on whether you use "tail recursion" or not.

As a side note, your coding & indention style is unreadable and unsafe. Use a new line for each line follow an if/else and always use `{}` for every if/else statement.

Comment: (As a rule of thumb, the only case where it makes sense to use recursion, is the case where it makes sense to use recursion.)

Comment: When should we use recursion? I just found that many algorithm demos used recursion so I tried to practise :(

Comment: @redcap On a more serious note, the only cases where it makes sense is when you are doing binary search, binary ("merge") sort, binary tree insert/search and similar. These are cases where recursion would likely make the algorithm _more_ readable, and that's the only places where you should use it. Recursion can _always_ be unrolled into a plain loop, but that loop is not necessarily more readable.